# I am not able to console.log() JSON data in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using axios to fetch data from api endpoint. I am using `getAllUser()` method to fetch data and `displayUsers()` to display `userName` and `email`from the data. I am not able to to get the JSON response in console. I also saw XHR in chrome but the request is not made to that API endpoint. Please tell me what should I change in `getAllUser()` and `displayUsers()` as I think I am doing something wrong in these methods.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          userList:[]
    }
  }

  ComponentDidMount(){
        if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("ud") !== null){
            var _userData = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("ud"));
            this.userDetails = _userData;
        }
        this.getAllUser();
  }

  getAllUser(){
        axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:"http://62.210.93.54:6010/api/getAllUser",
            auth:{
                username:this.userDetails.email,
                password:this.userDetails.password
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({
                userList:response.data.results
            })    
        })
  }

  displayUsers(){
        return this.state.userList.map( user => {
          return(
            <div className="item-card">
               <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
               </div>
            <div className="del-wrap">
                <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
            </div>
            </div>
            );
        })
  }

  render() {
        return(
          <div className="users-wrap">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                <div className="task-content">
                    <div className="user-wrap">
                        <div className="users">
                            <div className="item-card add">
                                    <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon" />
                                    <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
                             </div>

                             {this.displayUsers()}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The JSON response should have 4 objects and model schema looks like this:

```
 {
  "results": [
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": "Ankit",
      "createdDate": 1523892363509,
      "updatedDate": 1524066767311,
      "id": "5ad4c1964417fc66067b29cf",
      "userName": "admin",
      "email": "ankit@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "USER"
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1523971940177,
      "updatedDate": 1523971940177,
      "id": "5ad5f7640ff4ec580b885a2e",
      "userName": "varun",
      "email": "varun@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "ADMIN"
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1524302563169,
      "updatedDate": 1524302563169,
      "id": "5adb02e30ff4ec53076ffbb7",
      "userName": "Rahul",
      "email": "rahul@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "admin"
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1524303894654,
      "updatedDate": 1524303894654,
      "id": "5adb08160ff4ec53076ffbbb",
      "userName": "Nandita",
      "email": "nandita@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "member"
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1524308787960,
      "updatedDate": 1524308787960,
      "id": "5adb1b330ff4ec53076ffbc2",
      "userName": "user",
      "email": "user@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "USER"
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "updatedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1524327504461,
      "updatedDate": 1524327504461,
      "id": "5adb64500ff4ec53076ffbc4",
      "userName": "Rinku",
      "email": "test@woocation.com",
      "roles": [
        "admin"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "httpStatus": "OK",
  "message": "All Users response"
}
```

Comment: add `.catch` in `getAllUsers` to see if that request is not failing.

Comment: As per Thomas's comment, if you use `.then`, always also have `.catch`

Comment: I think the promise returns an error, it will be good you add a catch part to the promise. Because console.log will always print data if it exist.

Comment: @Lekens No it was a typo. I spent almost 2 hours debugging it. Can you suggest me some syntax checker or spell checker as I am using sublime text and it does not detect spelling for reactjs.

Comment: please use webstorm instead of sublime text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo when you use the lifecycle hooks:

`componentDidMount() {}` instead of `ComponentDidMount() {}` (no capital C)

Comment: Oh ok got it. There was a typo but now it works fine. Thanks for pointing it out. I am using sublime text how can I use spell checker or syntax check for reactjs. I almost wasted 2 hours debugging it but now understood it was a typo.

Comment: You can use vscode with reactjs code snippets or find a similar alternative in sublime text.

Comment: @Nenu Oh Ok so it is common in software development. I thought that I am missing some tools like syntax checker or something else. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Well "syntax checker" like [eslint](https://eslint.org/) could help you to prevent writting buggy code, but it will not warn you for this specific case. Nothing avoids you to create a class method called `ComponentDidMount` with a capital **C**. This is correct, even if this is really confusing.